# Can I able to run the test parallely in both parent and child tab in java ? (selenium TestNG )

Tags: java, selenium, testing, testng

I have a scenario to run two different tests parallelly to verify the location. My requirements is to run in two tabs. Each tab is completely independent.

Can I able to implement this by using **`driver.getHandles()`**?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no. If you want to run multiple tests in parallel then you must have multiple driver instances. If you are using multiple driver instances then multiple browser windows will be opened. You cannot open the multiple tabs and start the execution of the selenium test scripts in parallel WITH THE SAME WEBDRIVER INSTANCE.

Comment: Thank you for your input. Can you please clear my other doubts too. I created 2 test (using @Test) in my class. Each test will verify some data based on ID for every single minute.  In xml file, i added the attributes parallel and thread count. I am using maven command to run the test. But my tests are not executing parallelly. What is i am missing.(Like you mentioned i have created two different browser instances)

Comment: Could you please share the xml file with me. I believe that in parallel you  must specify the methods as value and in the thread count you need to specify 2 as value.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="ParallelView" parallel="methods" thread-count="2">

    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="utility.Listeners"/>
    </listeners>

    <test name="ParallelView">
        <classes>
            <class name="ParallelPassengerView">
            </class>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>

Comment: Could you please send some code here. Because with the same configuration I am able to run the test methods in parallel.

Comment: class ViewTest {

 String[] deviceID = {"DID1", "DID2"};

/Test1
 public void CompareVideoInFirstBrowser() throws Exception
{
      ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();

      driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);

      driver.manage().window().maximize();

      Thread.sleep(5000);

      URL = "urlBase" + companyName + "/" + deviceID[0];

      Thread.sleep(10000);

      driver.get(URL);

      comparePassengerView(driver, duration);
}
/Test2
public void CompareVideoInSecondBrowser() throws Exception
{
//Same code as above except deviceID
}
}